# React Scroll Parallax Background jumps/resizes upon mobile URL bar resize

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, parallax

I am using the [React Scroll Parallax](https://react-scroll-parallax.damnthat.tv/docs/intro) lib in a Next JS project to add a parallax effect to the background of a div on my main page. Here is a snippet from my home index.tsx

```
import { ParallaxBanner, ParallaxBannerLayer } from "react-scroll-parallax";

    <div className="main-container">
            <div className="home-background-container">
              <ParallaxBanner>
                <ParallaxBannerLayer speed={-70}>
                  <div className="home-background-bg"></div>
                </ParallaxBannerLayer>
              </ParallaxBanner>
            </div>
            {/* Other main content... */}
    </div>
```

The CSS for the classes above are:

```
.main-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.home-background-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}

.home-background-bg {
  background-image: url(/images/bell.svg);
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

This has achieved the result I want generally, which is for there to be a parallax background behind the main content, and it looks how I want it on desktop; however on mobile the background jumps position whenever the url bar of the browser resizes.

Why is this happening and how do I prevent it? I am willing to re-think my approach or use a different library if needed.